# [move_base] make_plan service is returning an empty path

Tags: navigation, move-base

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi!

I am working on autonomous exploration, and I am using **move_base** package for navigation tasks.

I wanted to use *make_plan* service of **move_base** package, but it's returning me an empty path even if the destination is reachable if you send it as a goal.

Has anyone faced with the same issue?

Here the code which calls *make_plan* service:

```
geometry_msgs::PoseStamped Start;
    Start.header.seq = 0;
    Start.header.stamp = Time(0);
    Start.header.frame_id = "map";
    Start.pose.position.x = x1;
    Start.pose.position.y = y1;
    Start.pose.position.z = 0.0;
    Start.pose.orientation.x = 0.0;
    Start.pose.orientation.y = 0.0;
    Start.pose.orientation.w = 1.0;

geometry_msgs::PoseStamped Goal;
    Goal.header.seq = 0;
    Goal.header.stamp = Time(0);
    Goal.header.frame_id = "map";
    Goal.pose.position.x = x2;
    Goal.pose.position.y = y2;
    Goal.pose.position.z = 0.0;
    Goal.pose.orientation.x = 0.0;
    Goal.pose.orientation.y = 0.0;
    Goal.pose.orientation.w = 1.0;

ServiceClient check_path = nh_.serviceClient<nav_msgs::GetPlan>("make_plan");
    nav_msgs::GetPlan srv;
    srv.request.start = Start;
    srv.request.goal = Goal;
    srv.request.tolerance = 1.5;

    ROS_INFO("Make plan: %d", (check_path.call(srv) ? 1 : 0));
    ROS_INFO("Plan size: %d", srv.response.plan.poses.size());
```

Here is the code to send *MoveBaseGoal* which works and robot moves to the same destination:

```
move_base_msgs::MoveBaseGoal move_goal;

    move_goal.target_pose.header.frame_id = "map";
    move_goal.target_pose.header.stamp = Time(0);

    move_goal.target_pose.pose.position.x = x;
    move_goal.target_pose.pose.position.y = y;
    move_goal.target_pose.pose.position.z = 0.0;
    move_goal.target_pose.pose.orientation.x = 0.0;
    move_goal.target_pose.pose.orientation.y = 0.0;
    move_goal.target_pose.pose.orientation.w = 1.0;

    ROS_INFO("Sending goal");
    ac_.sendGoal(move_goal,
             boost::bind(&ExploreAction::doneCb, this, _1, _2));
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/264369/%5Bmove_base%5D-make_plan-service-is-returning-an-empty-path/) by [saken](https://answers.ros.org/users/29297/saken/) on ROS Answers with karma: 161 on 2017-06-21

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

you need to check service name.

ServiceClient check_path = nh_.serviceClient<nav_msgs::GetPlan>("make_plan");

--> ServiceClient check_path = nh_.serviceClient<nav_msgs::GetPlan>("/move_base/make_plan");

Thanks.

---

Originally posted by [Jacbo](https://answers.ros.org/users/31821/jacbo/) with karma: 16 on 2017-09-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0